# Title page line spacing

Tags: titles, line-spacing

I have a simple problem but I didn't manage to find any answer for it. In my title page, I just used

```
\title{Name of the title}
```

then

```
\hrule height 0,1cm \leavevmode \\[0,5cm] 
   {\Huge{\textbf{\@title}}}\\[0,5cm]
\hrule height 0,1cm \leavevmode \\[0,5cm]
```

to print the title of my document.
But it takes more than 3 lines on the PDF file, and I have a different spacing between the 1st and 2nd line compared to the 2nd and 3rd, which is a bit frustrating.

Anyone got an idea of why ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal (and compilable) working example?

Comment: Word of advice, don't even use those line. Your title is enough to get attention, it won't need those line to further attract possible readers.

Comment: Please post your MWE http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3343/90087

Comment: May i ask where the original snippet is coming from? Maybe they want to improve their stuff.

Answer (score 4):

You gotta use paragraphs, not line breaks.

They guy who invented that dreadful rule business put that on wikibooks and it lives on. Better use no lines at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\hrule height 0,1cm \leavevmode \\[0,5cm] 
{\Huge\textbf{ The incredible journey of Walter~Wombat }}\\[0,5cm]
\hrule height 0,1cm \leavevmode \\[0,5cm]

%Output of the screenshot
\begin{center}
\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}\par
{\huge\bfseries The incredible journey of Walter~Wombat \par}
\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}\par
\bigbreak
{\Large Carl Capybara\par}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: quentinTitle]

Comment: That is what I was looking for. For what is the showframe package, though ?

Comment: @Quentin Showing the frame of the text block. My title with your method is faulty and sticks into the margin. When stuff like that happens, something's dodgy.

Comment: i'd be inclined to "tie" `Walter~Wombat` to avoid the ungraceful splitting of a proper name.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Very good point, edited.

Comment: uh, please take a look at what you've got there -- two code instances of the title, but the title only appears once.  i'm confused.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I just noticed now that the screenshot was absolutely not matching the code. I fixed that. But the answer isn't very good, i wonder if it would be better to delete it. Egreg has posted an answer as well.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sometimes i wonder if i am a complete mental case. Please have a look at that: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepageExamples/blob/master/quail.tex No need to *tie* the name there.

Comment: the `github` example has an explicit `\\ ` break.  the tie is an alternative that (usually) does the "right thing" if the line width is changed.  the reason i use the tie is so that the tied words are kept together when the heading string is also sent to the toc, where the line length, font size, etc., are almost certain to be different.

Comment: egreg's answer has a `\Huge` font; yours is only `\huge`.  so in effect, the line width is different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43654/discussion-between-johannes-b-and-barbara-beeton).

Answer (score 1):

I find a 1mm thick rule is too heavy. Anyhow, you can use `\hrule` so the spacing is better controlled. The trick is that TeX doesn't insert interline glue around `\hrule`

Add `\vspace*{-\topskip}` if you want the top rule to start from at the very beginning of the type block.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\vspace*{-\topskip}
\Huge\bfseries
\hrule height 1mm

\vspace{1ex}

The incredible journey of Walter Wombat

\vspace{1ex}

\hrule height 1mm
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]