# Line distance changes during the title

Tags: titles, thesis

The line distance in my title of my Master Thesis changes from the second to the third line. My code looks as follows:

Cover sheet:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}

\sffamily

\textbf{\huge\title}

\vspace*{2.8cm}

\framebox[15.5cm]{\textbf{\huge\thesis}}

\vspace*{1.6cm}

...
```

Definition file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,bibtotoc,oneside,10pt]{scrreprt} 

\def\title{Latex changes the line distance of my title from the second to the third line. I don't know whats the problem...}
```

[image: My outcome Looks like this]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I guess this happens as no character in the second line descends below the baseline. Can you try what happens if you add `\vphantom{j}` somewhere in the second line?

Comment: one common situation resulting in this kind of problem is the failure of the multi-line text to end with a `\par`.  since you have changed the font size to `\huge` i assume that the original size was smaller, and therefore the baselines of the block will be set to fit the original size.  (lack of descenders in the next-to-last line just makes things worse.)

Comment: hmm… only happens if there are braces around, like `{\bfseries\huge\title}`. I'm baffled. *barbare beeton* seems to be on to something, as adding `\par` at end seems to solve it.

Comment: wow, thank you for the quick answers.
The Suggestion with `\vphantom{j}` solved my Problem.
Thank you samcarter!

Comment: [Title page line spacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309861)