# Avoid long title overlapping in title page

Tags: titles

Does someone know how can I prevent my title text slightly overlapping like this?

(I have to say that it is something that happens only with my current thesis title: if I put different words it does not happen - this is why I kept some of the problematic words in the example)

[image]

This is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{BlackBox}\\
        \vspace{4em}
        {\Large \textsc{University something\\ ``Some Name''}}\\
        \vspace{1em}
        {\Large \textsc{Faculty of Engineering, Information Technology and Statistics}}\\
        \vspace{1em}
        {\small \textsc{Master of Science in Engineering in Computer Science}}\\
        \vspace{3em}
        {\normalsize Master of Science presentation}\\
        \vspace{2em}
        {\LARGE \textbf{ This Is My Very Long Title Analysis from Advertisements for Characterizing Industry Differences.}}\\
    \end{center}

    \vskip 2 cm
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c c c r}
            \textbf{Candidate} & & & & & & & & & \textbf{Supervisor} \\[0.2cm]
            \large{Name Surname} & & & & & & & & & \large{Name Surname}\\[0.3cm]
            \textbf{} & & & & & & & & & \textbf{External Supervisor} \\[0.2cm]
            \large{} & & & & & & & & & \large{Name Surname}\\[0.3cm]
            \footnotesize{ID 1234567}  & & & & & & & & &  \\[0.3cm]
        \end{tabular}

        \normalsize A.y. 2016/2017
    \end{center}


\end{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should end your paragraphs using `\par` as in the following example: `{\LARGE \textbf{long title}\par}`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309861/title-page-line-spacing

Answer (score 0):

like this?

[image]

i slightly clean up your code from wrong use of font size in font faces:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{BlackBox}\\
        \vspace{3em}
        \Large\scshape
        University something\\
        ``Some Name''       \\
        \vspace{1em}
        Faculty of Engineering, Information Technology and Statistics\\
        \vspace{1em}
        \small
        Master of Science in Engineering in Computer Science        \\
        \vspace{3em}
        \normalsize
        Master of Science presentation \\
        \vspace{2em}
        \normalfont\bfseries\LARGE
            This Is My Very Long Title Analysis from
            Advertisements for Characterizing Industry Differences.
    \end{center}
    \vspace{1.5 cm}
    \begin{center}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
        \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r}
            \textbf{Candidate}          &   \textbf{Supervisor}     \\
            \large Name Surname         &   \large Name Surname     \\
                                        &   \textbf{External Supervisor} \\
                                        &   \large Name Surname     \\
            \footnotesize ID 1234567    &
        \end{tabular*}

        A.y. 2016/2017
    \end{center}


\end{titlepage}
%\maketitle
\end{document}
```